# Bytes are not sent to the serial driver buffer

Tags: c, posix

I have this program:

```
// C headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// POSIX headers
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

// Other headers
#include "ZL_sleep.h"
#include "ZL_utf8.h"
#include "ZL_serial.h"

#define BS 4 // Buffer size

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    int32_t p; // Port
    int32_t r; // Read finished
    uint8_t b[BS]; // Buffer
    uint32_t n; // Number of bytes to be read from driver buffer

    if(argc != 2){
        printf("ERROR: Supply a \"serial port\" device file.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    p = ZL_open_tty(argv[1]);
    if(p < 0){
        perror("ERROR: open()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(1){
        memset(b, '\0', BS);
        r = read(p, b, BS);

        if(r < 0){
            if(errno == EAGAIN){
            }
            else{
                perror("ERROR: read()");
                close(p);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        ZL_utf8_print_bytes(b, BS);
        putchar('\n');

    }

    close(p);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

that uses function `ZL_utf8_print_bytes()` that prints the buffer bytes *(one by one in a for loop)*. It also calls function `ZL_open_tty()` and passes the `argv[1]` (**`/dev/pts/1`**) to it as an argument.

Function `ZL_open_tty()` function sets `O_NONBLOCK` flag with `open()` in order for `open()` to return immediately i.e. *"nonblocking"* with whatever status. Then before any other I/O function is used, function clears `O_NONBLOCK` flag and switches back to *"blocking"*. It then sets `VMIN` and `VTIME` so that `read()`:

> blocks until `VMIN` or more *bytes* is received/exists in driver
> buffer. *(It may block indefinitely)*

```
uint32_t ZL_open_tty(const char * terminal){

    uint32_t fd; // File's descriptor
    uint32_t fl; // File's flags
    struct termios fo; // File's options

    fd = open(terminal, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if(fd < 0){
        return -1;
    }
    
    fl = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
    if(fl < 0){
        perror("ERROR: fcntl():");
        return -1;
    }
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, fl & ~(O_NONBLOCK | O_APPEND | O_DSYNC | O_RSYNC | O_SYNC));
    
    tcgetattr(fd, &fo);
    fo.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    fo.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &fo);

    fputs("───────────────────────────────────────────────────  terminal settings\n", stdout);
    printf("VMIN = %d\n", fo.c_cc[VMIN]);
    printf("VTIME = %d\n", fo.c_cc[VTIME]);
    putchar('\n');
    return(fd);
```

Afterwards my program enters an endless while loop where `read()` blocks until I enter any key when keyboard focus is in **`/dev/pts/1`**.

The problem that I am facing is that sometimes I press a key in **`/dev/pts/1`** and bytes registered with this key aren't transmitted to the driver buffer?! Bytes just stays in the **`/dev/pts/1`**. This happens with ASCII (1-byte) characters and UTF8 (multi-byte) bytes...

I know that `read()` tries to read *requested* amount of bytes (`BS`) from the driver buffer. But it reads less bytes if there aren't `BS` bytes available in the driver buffer. So... if some bytes would arrive later it could read them later. But these bytes never arrive to the driver buffer for some reason...

What could be causing bytes not to arrive in the driver buffer and remain forever in the **`/dev/pts/1`**?

[image]

Comment: don't you also need to disable canonical mode? ICANON...

Comment: I added `fo.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
` in the `ZL_open_tty()` to disable the canonical mode and results are identical.

Comment: Even if I try to only request to read `1` byte like so `r = read(p, b, 1);` some bytes are not transfered to the serial driver buffer and are therefore not read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pts` was created when a virtual terminal was attached to the system (usually `ssh`). The `pts` was connected as `stdin`/`stdout` for a shell which was started for the connection, therefore you already have a process attached to the `pts` and reading from it.

Once you attach your application, you effectively start a race between both processes (your application and the shell), so whoever is faster will receive the content of the buffer. The character had not remained in the buffer of the `pts`, rather it was read by the shell attached to the `pts`.

To be able to read without interruption from the attached process, you need to intercept the buffer of the `pts` by informing the master multiplexer `ptmx`, see more in [ptmx(4)](https://linux.die.net/man/4/ptmx). You can study how it's done in the [interceptty](https://github.com/geoffmeyers/interceptty)